# Issue reading with DataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, .net

I got a XML file like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SPs>
  <SP>
    <seq>A01</seq>
    <id>001</id>
    <sp_desc>Stored Procedure 001</sp_desc>
    <sp_name>getCategory</sp_name>
    <para1_name>CategoryID</para1_name>
    <para2_name>CategoryName</para2_name>
    <para3_name></para3_name>
    <para4_name></para4_name>
    <para5_name></para5_name>
    <para1_value>1</para1_value>
    <para2_value>Hardware Solutions</para2_value>
    <para3_value></para3_value>
    <para4_value></para4_value>
    <para5_value></para5_value>
    <outputas>myreport-{DateTime}.xlsx</outputas>
    <status>1</status>
  </SP>

</SPs>
```

I can load it via DataSet's ReadXML method, no problem on that.

When I'm using the below code, i got Column Count of 16 :

```
myDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable().Columns.Count
```

When I got below XML, it seems that it can't recognised the 4 parameter fields and now it got returned with Column Count of 14.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SPs>
  <SP>
    <seq>A01</seq>
    <id>001</id>
    <sp_desc>Stored Procedure 001</sp_desc>
    <sp_name>getCategory</sp_name>
    <para1_name type="string">CategoryID</para1_name>
    <para2_name type="string">CategoryName</para2_name>
    <para3_name type="string"></para3_name>
    <para4_name type="string"></para4_name>
    <para5_name type="string"></para5_name>
    <para1_value>1</para1_value>
    <para2_value>Hardware Solutions</para2_value>
    <para3_value></para3_value>
    <para4_value></para4_value>
    <para5_value></para5_value>
    <outputas>myreport-{DateTime}.xlsx</outputas>
    <status>1</status>
  </SP>

</SPs>
```

Is there something we can do so that it returns as 16?

Eventually I would like to access to:

```
myDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable().Columns
```

Comment: Do you mean column count of 12? And why not just `myDS.Tables[0].Columns.Count`?

Comment: when i do myDS.Tables[0].Columns.Count, it seems that it returns as 12 as well. So the issue may not be the AsEnumerable()

Comment: I don't know exactly what rules the DataSet uses to read xml but that sample xml creates 6 data tables, not one. Each of the elements with a `type` attribute is becoming it's own DataTable. You might consider reading the xml with `XDocument` and manually creating a `DataTable` instead of using `DataSet.ReadXml()`.